# Storing information in files to faster access

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I have list of strings:  [ 'a', 'b']. I want to create some shell script, which for the first call return 'a', for second 'b'. I know following ways to do it.

1. To create two files 1(content:a), 2(content:b), then create third file which keep current number - pointer. When I just open file with name from third file and increment this number.  But if list is large I have to keep a lot of files.
2. Keep all strings of list line-wise in one file, create second file for number-pointer, which in this case point to the specific line of first file. But in this case, for last lines of list OS also have to iterate from all preceding lines in first file.
3. We can change file itself, say always take first line and then delete first line from it, but still deleting line with something like `cat 1 | tail $((length-1)) >1` also seems expensive operation, which demand copying of all lines. Maybe this method can be improved by some OS-dependent way of shifting pointer to the beginning of file?

So the question is: what is the best way to perform such thing?

Comment: Can you let your shell script know, whether it is the first or the second invocation (maybe by an additional parameter)? It would then be trivial to pick the correct field. Or, you use a second file ("session.txt"), where your shell script remembers the number of times it has been invoked already.

Answer (score 1):

Create a FIFO. Have a script repeatedly `cat` the file to the FIFO. Have other processes read a single line from the FIFO.

Comment: If I understand correctly in this case I should iterate from all file  without killing first process. But I want to get next element of list when I need it, after year, for example.

Comment: If you only need to read one line per year then why even care how efficient it is?

Comment: Perfectionism. All solutions seem have some ugly elements. I just wonder is there better solution?